# How does Google Calendar do their reminders?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api

I am looking at google calendar and wondering how they did their reminders.

Currently I have just a calendar and they choose a date when they want to be notified. This does not expand very well if I want to do reminders for hours and minutes.

So do they have like a field in their database that has like "hours,days,minutes" as a possible field?

Or do they store dates and they just query for that date and time. So if I want a hour before my appointment(say it is Feb 3rd 3:00pm) then they just store feb 3rd 2:00pm)

So they would store Feb 3rd 2:00 pm and on the hour just query for dates that match the current hour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyone who knows such information would be very unlikely to reveal it on a public forum like this. Rather than find out how Google Calendar happens to work, I suggest you think about solving *your* requirements. Aside from anything else, I doubt that you have to scale quite as much as Google Calendar :)

You may want to choose to store the number of minutes for the reminder as a lowest common denominator - so you'd store an hour as 60 minutes. I doubt that the user would mind if they entered 60 minutes and it was displayed as one hour.

Storing the absolute time is useful in some ways (simple querying), but it means that if you change the start date/time you also need to recompute the reminder date/time.

(As I say, this isn't giving any hints about how Google Calendar does things.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Ya ok I doubt someone will tell me how it exactly works but maybe someone can theorize how they did. So your way would be always storing the minutes?

Comment: @chobo2: I think it would depend on how the rest of the application worked, to be honest. There's merits for storing *both* the minutes and the absolute time, but equally there are merits for each other way too. How are you sending the notifications?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I think the absolute time is a good way to go but of course that requires storing the number(so when they come to change the reminder there is a number to populate the textbox). However I am not sure how to do the actual gathering. Like say if I do hours and I query everything for 2pm but till my method is triggered it is 2:01pm so it would miss all the ones that would be 2pm bound. I guess if that would happen I could grab all missed reminders and send them along.

Comment: @chobo2: Of course you *could* calculate the minutes from the absolute time, to populate the textbox. It depends how you want to achieve it. I'm not quite sure about your follow-on question... you'd want to find all reminders which should be sent between your last query and the current one, or something like that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Ya I could that as well. That would save a field in the db. Still trying to figure out how grab the queries. At first I was thinking of running it once every hour and goes just before the next hour. However the problem with this is that it is not really then a hour before notification. Like if a user appointment is at 3:13 pm and then want to be notified a hour earlier the emails should come at 2:13pm but if I am doing it at every hour it would be sent at 3pm.

Comment: @chobo2: Yes, you want to *either* query very frequently, or have some sort of "queue for messages in the next hour" which you can work through appropriately.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Since I am a shared hosting I would probably not do it more than every 15minutes(5 minutes is the lowest I could go anyways as that is what http://www.weetasks.com/default.aspx supports and I prefer this way then having something like "Quartz") . Are you talking about some sort of email queue since that might work. Maybe grab all the messages for the next 15 minutes and put it in a queue and launch when needed.  I have to look into email queuing as I don't know much about it.

Comment: I was thinking of something like Quartz, actually - that should be able to schedule for you easily.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I am have not used quartz really so I am not sure if it would make it easier for me then what I am currently using. I only want to grab I guess all the reminder in a 15 minute time frame then check those reminders maybe every minute and send them out.  That way I am only hitting the db 4 times a hour but then using a queue or a thread maybe to check the results of that 15 minutes and sending out the ones that need to hit at a certain time.

Comment: @chobo2: I would certainly look into Quartz. Given that this is exactly the kind of thing it's meant for, it's likely to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I came here to ask this question myself. My personal theory is that they somehow set up cron jobs to fire at the set times. But they must also be able to delete/update those jobs as well. I'm running a reminder style service, the best I have done is to run a scheduled task once a day to send out anything with that date on it. I would like to offer more flexibilty, but haven't theorized how to do it, and figured the stack collective could come up with a better way than I have...

Answer (score 0):

It's no good speculating how Google does it; Whatever Google uses, it's backed by a truly massive server cluster, and is probably far more involved than you need. For a smaller app, even an enterprise-level app, there are straightforward methods to accomplish this.

For the schema, I would store the appointment as an ordinary date/time, and the reminder either as another date/time (which you can calculate given hours and minutes using the TimeSpan structure), or as the number of Ticks in a TimeSpan. There are advantages and disadvantages to either; using a date/time reminder, you must recalculate that date/time if the appointment changes. But, the reminder time is human-readable when stored in schema. The opposite is true for storing the value as ticks; 15 minutes in TimeSpan ticks is 15 minutes, and you can add that to any datetime they specify for the actual appointment. But, it's just going to be a big number in the DB, requiring users to use your app to understand the data.

You can store one reminder for an appointment on the appointment record itself, or you can allow many pre-scheduled reminders per appointment by maintaining a separate table that references the appointment record and contains the reminder time.

For the actual reminder implementation, an app (or piece of functionality therein) that you create to handle these reminders should query the database for the first reminder of interest to the current user that will occur first, and set a timer to expire at the designated time. That thread will simply sleep for the required number of milliseconds, then fire an event which you'll use to show the reminder.

Comment: Good point. MANY server clusters. When a network reaches a certain size it starts becoming irrelevant where they're actually physically located; you need networking hardware you normally see in an ISP's warehouse just to have them all talk to each other.